# Rails console uninitialized constant MiniTest::Test (NameError) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

I use Rails. 3.2.16, with Rspec.

Recently when I run `rails console` I get the following error:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:28:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant MiniTest::Test (NameError)
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:4:in `<module:Test>'
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb:312:in `initialize_console'
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

When I run `rails server` there are no problems.

Since I use Rspec, I don't have minitest in my Gemfile. However when I run `gem list` I can see:

```
minitest (5.3.3, 5.3.2, 4.7.5, 4.3.2)
```

And I am not sure why this suddenly happens.

#### Additional note

@user3364461 may have a related issue:

> With RVM and last bundler (1.6.2) ruby 2.1.1, and rails 4.1. Happen
>   when I've updated some gem (Axlsx-rails, minitest, arel) If I force
>   minitest 5.3.2, it's the same bug with arel :
>
> Could not find minitest-5.3.3 in any of the sources Run bundle install
>   to install missing gems.